# if there are two spaces, it will count it as 3 words

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (){

  int ch;
  unsigned long int charcount=0;
  unsigned long int wordcount=0;
  unsigned long int linecount=0;

  while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
    if (ch!=' '&& ch!='\n'){ 
      charcount++;
    } 
    if(ch==' '|| ch=='\n'){
      wordcount++;
    }
    if (ch=='\n'){
      linecount++;
    }
  }

printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount );
return 0;
}
```

The question is: a C program called that counts the number of characters, words and lines read from standard input until EOF is reached.
Words are defined as contiguous sequences of letters (a through z, A through Z) and the apostrophe ( ', value 39 decimal) separated by any character outside these ranges.
Lines are defined as contiguous sequences of characters separated by newline characters ('\n').
Characters beyond the final newline character will not be included in the line count.

For most cases it counts the number of words correctly, but I don't think my condition for wordcount is correct

Comment: Your code does not do what you say in the text.  For example a sequence like this <space><space><\n>   will get counted as 3 words when in fact it is 0 words.  (The < and > are not characters but <…> is a character).  You need to look for the a-z, A-Z ' stuff to start a word.  You are not doing this.

Comment: There are a few libc functions that will help you with your task, they're in `ctype.h`  you might want to look at: `isalpha` `isspace` etc..

Comment: Blanks and newlines are both countable characters under the normal rules of "what is a character".  You normally need to keep track of whether you are in a word or not, and spot when you transition from 'in a word' to 'not in a word' or vice versa.  You need to start 'not in a word'.  It's a little unusual to count '`a1b2c3d`' as 4 words, but your rules say that's what should happen — your code doesn't pay any attention to that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not correctly handling word separators.  Instead, it contains the assumption that any word separator marks the end of a word.  So it is counting a word even when no word has started.

There are many ways you might approach this, but the general idea is to maintain some kind of state which represents that you are either in a word, or you are between words.

Here is one such example:

```
int wordcount = 0;
int betweenwords = 1;
while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    if (!isspace(ch)) {
        wordcount += betweenwords;
        betweenwords = 0;
    }
    else {
        betweenwords = 1;
    }
}
```

This doesn't follow the same criteria for a word as your program (mine is treating all non-space characters as words), but it would be quite simple to adapt.  The point here is to understand that you can use some kind of state variable to determine whether to increment your word count or not.  In my example, the state variable is also used as the increment.